# How to upload image using django rest framework and angular?

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework

I am working on a project where i am using django rest framework as backend and angular 6 as frontend. I am trying to upload a image from angular form. but it shows error ["The type of the image couldn't be determined."] when try to post data.

This is for my personal project which i want to develop using DRF,Angular and MySQL.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime


class Category(models.Model):
  cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  parent_cat_id = models.IntegerField()
  description = models.TextField()
  cat_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/')
  active = models.BooleanField()
  create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.cat_name

 class Meta:
    db_table = "category"
```

serializers.py

```
from drf_extra_fields.fields import Base64ImageField
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Category


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  cat_image = Base64ImageField()

  class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = ('id', 'cat_name', 'description', 'parent_cat_id', 'cat_image', 'active')
```

category.service.ts

```
createCategories(category) {
return this.http.post(this.globalService.baseUrl + 'Category/', 
category).subscribe(res => console.log('saved', res));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

in angular you should do like following :

template:

These lines are part of a form tag.

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <label>Logo (optional):</label>
    <input type="file"
     id="logo"
     name="logo"
     (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
  </div>
```

ts:

```
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
let fileItem = files.item(0);
let fileNameArr = fileItem.name.split('.');

if(fileNameArr[1] == 'jpg' || fileNameArr[1] == 'JPG' || fileNameArr[1] == 'png' || fileNameArr[1] == 'PNG'){

  this.errorMessage = '';
  this.fileToUpload = fileItem;

}else{
  this.errorMessage = 'logo should be in jpg or png format';
  this.fileToUpload = null;
}
```

function that call api service :

```
signUpForm(form: NgForm){



let newUser = {
  full_name: form.value.full_name,
  facility_name: form.value.facility_name,
};



let formData: FormData = new FormData();

// logo file is optional
if(this.fileToUpload)
  formData.append('logo_company', this.fileToUpload, this.fileToUpload.name);

for(let key in newUser){
  formData.append(key, newUser[key]);
}

//call membership service for sign up
this.membershipService.registerUser(formData).subscribe(
  (data: any) => {
    // this.spinnerService.hide();
    this.isDisplaySpinner = false;
    window.alert('You signed up to web site successfully.\nAn activation link sent to your email. Refer to your email please and click on it.');
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  },
  (error: any) => {
    // this.spinnerService.hide();
    this.isDisplaySpinner = false;

    if(error.email)
      this.errorMessage = error.email;
    else
      this.errorMessage = error;
  }
);
```

}

In serializer class do not define cat_image,

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'cat_name', 'description', 'parent_cat_id', 'cat_image', 'active')
```

Comment: "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form." Now showing this error.

Comment: congratulation!

Comment: onSelectedFile(event) {
           this.message = '';
           this.url = '';
            if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            const mimeType = event.target.files[0].type;
                if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
                   this.message = 'Only images are supported.';
                   return;
          }
               const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
               reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
              reader.onload = (_event) => {
               this.url = reader.result;
       };
   } }